# Creating list of objects using data from numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, object, numpy

I have several numpy arrays containing data, and a class I defined, with attributes corresponding to each of my numpy arrays. I would like to quickly make another array containing a list of objects, with each objects attributes defined by the corresponding element of the numpy array. Basically, the equivalent of the following:

```
class test:
     def __init__ (self, x, y): 
          self.x = x
          self.y = y  
a = np.linspace(100)
b = np.linspace(50)  
c = np.empty(len(a), dtype = object)    
for i in range(len(a)):
    c[i] = test(a[i], b[i])
```

So, my question is does there exist a more concise and pythonic way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That iteration is 'pythonic'.

`numpy` does have a function that works in this case, and may be a bit faster.  It's not magical:

```
In [142]: a=np.linspace(0,100,10)
In [143]: b=np.linspace(0,50,10)   # change to match a size
In [144]: f=np.frompyfunc(test,2,1)
In [145]: c=f(a,b)
In [146]: c
Out[146]: 
array([<__main__.test object at 0xb21df12c>,
       <__main__.test object at 0xb21dfb2c>,
       <__main__.test object at 0xb221a9cc>,
       <__main__.test object at 0xb222c44c>,
       <__main__.test object at 0xb2213d0c>,
       <__main__.test object at 0xb26bc16c>,
       <__main__.test object at 0xb2215c0c>,
       <__main__.test object at 0xb221598c>,
       <__main__.test object at 0xb21eb2cc>,
       <__main__.test object at 0xb21ebc6c>], dtype=object)
In [147]: c[0].x,c[1].y
Out[147]: (0.0, 5.555555555555555)
```

`frompyfunc` returns a function that applies the input `f` to elements of `a,b`.  I define it as taking 2 inputs, and returning 1 array.  By default it returns an object array, which suits your case.

`np.vectorize` uses this same function, but with some overhead that can make it easier to use.

It also handles broadcasting, so by changing an input into a column array I get a 2d output:

```
In [148]: c=f(a,b[:,None])
In [149]: c.shape
Out[149]: (10, 10)
```

But keep in mind that there isn't a lot that you can do with this `c`.  It's little more a list of `test` instances.  For example `c+1` does not work, unless you define a `__add__` method.